# Show that portfolio's percentage contribution to loss (PCL) equals PCR (risk)

Tags: risk, modern-portfolio-theory, self-study

I came across this question during self study on a quantitative book (Question 3.6 on Page 75 of *Quantitative Equity Portfolio Management: Modern Techniques and Applications* By Edward E. Qian, Ronald H. Hua, Eric H. Sorensen ), can someone help me out? I got stuck on **part(c)**. FYI, PCR = Percentage Contribution to Risk, PCL = Percentage Contribution to Loss, the definition for **PCR** is:
$$PCR_i=\frac{\omega_i\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial w_i}}{\sigma}$$
and I have already found the optimal $\displaystyle \omega^*$ and optimal $\displaystyle (\sigma^*)^2$ from mean-variance optimization problem formed as follows.
$$Maximize \ \ \ \ \ \  \omega^T\cdot f-\frac{1}{2}\lambda(\omega^T\Sigma\omega )\\
subject \ \ to  \ \ \ \ \ \ \omega ^T i=1$$

[image]

Comment: What is $f$ in your objective function

Comment: It seems like just a multivariate extension of what they have in the main text, where they use the conditional expectation of one normal random variable given the sum. The only novelty seems to be $\mu_R$ which might refer to $\mu_P$.

Comment: @develarist **f** is a input variable which stands for forecast return

Comment: expected (average) return $\mu$? And what is $\sigma$ in the PCR formula? portfolio $\sigma_p$ or asset $\sigma_i$?

Comment: @develarist $f$ is just the return for each stock, we can obtain expected return for the optimal portfolio by multiplying $f$ and $\omega^*$. Also $\sigma$ is total risk of the portfolio which is $\sigma_p$

Comment: @Magic is in the chain Yes, you are right. I also got stuck on bivariate part, can you give some hints on bivariate part and then I can deduce the general results?

Comment: What does $\frac{\partial\sigma_p}{\partial\omega_i} $ equal and reduce to?

Comment: It is really down to the use of this conditional expectation formula: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random